# is it OK to just change a tag on a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's one user that removes installation and replaces it with system-installation or software-installation.

Most of the questions are good questions with plus 15 votes. Should these edits be approved, because I think the change is too minor and changing every question from installation to software/system is just a crazy idea.

Like this suggested edit, https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/254730

Comment: Well, installation sounds like a classic meta tag and should probably be removed from all questions.

Answer (score 4):

I will change the question around. Is the only thing that can be *improved* in the question? Is the editor missing something else? What else can be improved in the post?

If the answers are: yes, no, nothing; yeah, approve the edit. It's a good edit and the user is doing a service. Now, normally retagging tasks are reserved to 2kers but if they don't do anything, if a user wants to help, I don't see anything wrong.