# Am I handling a suggested edit correctly?

Tags: discussion

Recently I have been seeing a large number of suggested edits from a single op, changing the tag on older questions from 'installation' to 'system-installation'  After the first dozen or so, I have started rejecting these edits as 'too minor' as a) this is the only edit to the question and b) The op *seems* to be either on a kick to replace all the 'installation' tags or to build reputation points 2 at a time, by finding all older posts with that tag.

An example of such a suggested edit is at https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/307128

Comment: Related (and *maybe* a duplicate): [is it OK to just change a tag on a question?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/9002/22949) Also, for some of the context behind these particular edits: [Blacklist the \[installation\] tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8233/22949), [Should we split the installation tag into seperate tags for the installation of Ubuntu and the installation of software?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7820/22949)

Comment: @EliahKagan  Very similar, but I should point out that the edits I'm referring to are to older questions, which others have already commented on or answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) tag is bad and should be replaced but I would note that some of these edits are missing other details that could be improved at the same time.

I would **approve** the ones where the post is otherwise fine and **improve** the ones (you can unmark the original as helpful if you think it was lazy), but ultimately, replacing the tag is a desirable long-term goal.

Not all [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) tags should be replaced with [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) (we have other `*-installation` tags) so check that the replacement makes sense too.

Answer (score 2):

Me too - same editor. I have rejected them all with the following custom reason:

> Please don't do simple tag edits. It is too minor, bungs up the review queue and can be seen as rep farming.

However, I will probably be changing that to

> Please don't do only simple tag edits. It is too minor, bungs up the review queue and can be seen as rep farming. Try to include body edits as well.

My pronouns are He / Him